# difference between key value in adressline and getId() value in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I wanted to ask what's the difference between the value in the adressline and the id I get when i use getId(). 
For example for one document the `getId()` value is:

```
t8K_TLQPmKzgB72pY4TblUg
```

while in the adressline the key is:

```
0Amu7sNvd2IoudDhLX1RMUVBtS3pnQjcycFk0VGJsVWc
```

what i figured out so far is that when you encode getId in base64 you get more or less the last part of the key in the adressline

```
 (base64Encode(t8K_TLQPmKzgB72pY4TblUg) = dDhLX1RMUVBtS3pnQjcycFk0VGJsVWc=).
```

But I still don't know what  `0Amu7sNvd2Iou` stands for, because i have the impression that this parts also is different in older documents, therefore i can't just combine the key using all the time `0Amu7sNvd2Iou` at the beginning

Why I need to know this: my scripts use the getId method but some users fill in their ids manually (they just copypaste it from the key from the adressline). The result is that when i try to compare them although they refer to the same document i can't match them like they are completly different...

thanks a lot for bringing light into this problem

edit @taras:
i can also open the document with the key and the id. It's just weird that there are kind of two different id's for one document. If for example i want to compare if a value somebody copypasted from the adressline to a document is the same as the file i have opened i won't get a true, even it is the same file

```
var keyFromHeadline = "0Amu7sNvd2IoudDhLX1RMUVBtS3pnQjcycFk0VGJsVWc"
var id = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getId();
if (keyFromHeadline==id) Browser.msgBox("blabla")
```

Therefore i would be interested what is the reason for the two different values and how i could match them

Comment: please add some illustrative code snippets - I can't observe what you describe. I can use Id or URL interchangably with following regex: `SpreadsheetApp.openById(e.parameter.newFile.replace(/.*key=/,'').replace(/[&#].*/,''));`

Comment: Are you talking about **script** files? Remember that script files sitting inside a document container have a different id than the enclosing container.

Comment: no i am talking about spreadsheet files

Comment: i think i figured it out, the first part might be the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to have unique file IDs just normalize them. Everytime a user enters an ID manually just run it trough the fileIdNormalize function:

```
function fileIdNormalize(id) {
  if (typeof id == 'string' && id.length > 0)
    return DocsList.getFileById(id).getId();
  return '';
}
```

Comment: smooth workaround, still i'd like to know if there is no way to get the key from the adressline via a script because i'd prefer to store that value so the user has no possibility to see that there are two different ids for the same document (risk of misunderstandings)

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion :

Since base64Encode seems to give you a significative part of the adress url you could use a `match` to check if the document is the same.

Something like :

```
    if('manually_entered_key'.match(base64Encode('the_value_obtained_by_getId')==base64Encode('the_value_obtained_by_getId')){
   // consider as the same doc ...
```

Comment: good idea, but i prefer to not use it, because I am afraid it will create later problems if somebody wants to add new code and is not aware of that workaround. Therefore i would be more interested in an explanation why there are two different keys or how i could write the value from the adressline to a spreadsheet